# RODBC - Why is my update query not working?

Tags: sql, r, sql-update, rodbc

I'm reading in a .csv file and comparing two fields, one in a table called "Col" and one in the .csv file called "newdata".  If they match I overwrite item_price in the "COL" table with the value of avg_price in "newdata".  I get no errors, but nothing is changed in COL.

```
library(RODBC)
db <- "C:/Projects/Online.accdb"
conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db) 
newData <- read.csv("C:/Projects/duplicates.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
for(row in 1:nrow(newData)){
  query <- paste0(
    "UPDATE COL 
    SET item_price = ",newData$avg_price[row], 
    "WHERE COL.generic ='",newData$generic[row],"'"  
    )
   sqlQuery(conn, query)
}
close(conn)
```

Comment: Can you print(query) within the loop and does it look like a correct sql that matches your Access db with a legit where clause?  If you execute one of those print(query) statements in the underlying Access manually does it change your COL as expected?

Comment: The item_price is not shown:[1] "UPDATE COL \n    SET item_price = WHERE COL.generic ='8440-20-008-7933'"

Comment: I assume I can just run a query within access to see where I went wrong, but I thought I could learn by doing in R.

Comment: what does head(newData) give you?

Comment: generic avg..cost
     1 8440-20-008-7933     6.070
     2 8440-20-001-0714     9.735
     3 8405-20-003-0729    20.540
     4 8315-21-868-7262     9.315
    5 8315-21-899-3717    19.190
    6 8315-21-899-3721     7.765

Comment: Can I turn it into code formatting?

Comment: It looks like the names in your csv file aren't the same as what you're referncing in your query.  Based on this, I'll propose you an answer below.  And yes, it would help if you can put code in by modifying your question with "dput(head(newData))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, suggest a fix below, which will change the column names of the input file to match the names of the query:

```
library(RODBC)
db <- "C:/Projects/Online.accdb"
conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db) 
newData <- read.csv("C:/Projects/duplicates.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
names(newData) <- c("generic","avg_price")
for(row in 1:nrow(newData)){
  query <- paste0("UPDATE COL SET item_price = ",newData$avg_price[row]," WHERE COL.generic ='",newData$generic[row],"'")
   sqlQuery(conn, query)
}
close(conn)
```

Comment: Soren, thanks very much for this.  One question, it seems that it only affects part of the table.  The table is over 3.5 million records.  Do you see something in the code that would limit the update query?

Comment: Glad it helped!  See what you get with "length(unique(newData$generic))" this will give you the total maximum number of updates you're passing to the database.  If the number you get here is, say, 100,000 then you can only expect that many updates.  If the number is close to 3.5 millions, then you may want to look more closely at the value(s) of newData$generic to see if that generic 'id' value is a legitimate value that exists in your database

Comment: The length(..) in newData is just 173.  That's just the length of the newData file.  It should be taking each record in newData, finding all records in COL that match it (out of 3.5 million records) and replace item_price in COL with the value in avg_price.  But it seems to stop doing the update after a few hundred matches.  Are you saying it will only update 173 records in COL for each match?

Comment: Its tough to say without seeing the data on both sides of the .csv file and the Access file, but it looks like your loop is working properly even if it's half-way working.  Where it's stopping working suggests it's not matching somehow.  Possibly the generic ID value is malformatted on one side or the other so it's not finding the match (maybe there are spaces or extra punctuation in there?).  If there's 173 unique csvID values, on your db you can do "select count(distinct generic) from COL" and see if there are 173 there to match against?

Comment: OK, I'll work it through.  I assume I also don't have to run a for loop through each record in the db.